# Pagination - Base URL duplicate

Tags: pagination

I have the following problem: 
- Let's say I'm on **domain.com/en/support/manuals** 
- Using pagination I get the following URL on Page 2: **domain.com/en/support/manuals/domain.com/en/support/manuals/P10**


Once I manually remove the duplicate part, it works just fine. Whats wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="manual" limit="10" paginate_base="support/manuals"}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <a href="{manual_download}">
      {manual_relationship}
        {manual_relationship:title}
      {/manual_relationship}
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="span2">
      {categories}{category_name} {/categories}
    </div>

    <div class="span2">
      {manual_size}
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>


  {paginate }
     <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
  {/paginate}

  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the template code bit that's displaying the problem URL?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you forgot about the protocol on the [URL to the root of your site](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/general_configuration.html#url-to-the-root-directory-of-your-site). Probably, you wrote `domain.com` instead of `http://domain.com`.

The duplicated part is added by the browser that is treating the URL as relative because of the absence of protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around. It appears that I need to use 'http://' in front of the pagination_url. The following version now works perfectly:

```
{paginate}
{pagination_links}
<ul>
       {first_page}
       <li><a href="http://{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
       {/first_page}

       {previous_page}
       <li><a href="http://{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
       {/previous_page}

       {page}
       <li><a href="http://{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
       {/page}

       {next_page}
       <li><a href="http://{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
       {/next_page}

       {last_page}
       <li><a href="http://{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
       {/last_page}

</ul>
{/pagination_links}
</div>
{/paginate}
```